# Filter JSON Array with dynamic conditions

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have many JSON array with different types of nodes in it.

Sample Json 1:

```json
[
    {
          "EmpID": "23",
          "EmpName": "Jhon",
          "Age": "23"
    },
    {
          "EmpID": "29",
          "EmpName": "Paul",
          "Age": "25"
    },
    {
          "EmpID": "123",
          "EmpName": "Jack",
          "Age": "29"
    },
    {
          "EmpID": "129",
          "EmpName": "Apr",
          "Age": "29"
    }
]
```

Sample Json 2

```json
[
    {
          "DepID": "2",
          "Name": "Sales"
    },
    {
          "DepID": "5",
          "Name": "Marketing"
    },
    {
          "DepID": "12",
           "Name": "IT"
    }
]
```

I want to filter them based on different conditions such as

1)EmpID=29

This should return

```json
[
    {
          "EmpID": "29",
           "EmpName": "Paul",
           "Age": "25",
    }
]
```

2)Age=23 and EmpName=Jhon

This should return

```json
[
    {
          "EmpID": "23",
           "EmpName": "Jhon",
           "Age": "23"
    }
]
```

3. Age=29

This should return

```json
[
    {
          "EmpID": "123",
           "EmpName": "Jack",
           "Age": "29"
    },
    {
          "EmpID": "129",
           "EmpName": "Apr",
           "Age": "29"
    }
]
```

So I need a generic approach to do any number of filters on the JSON array. I am planning to get all the filters using some comma separated string  like `Age="23",EmpName="Jhon"` and this can be converted to any format in the code.

I have tried creating dynamic filter using Json Path such as `$.[?(@.Age == '23' && @.EmpName == 'Jhon')]`.

Also I tried using LINQ like

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
var res = (result as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray).Where(x =>
           x["Age"].ToString() =="23" && x["EmpName"].ToString()=="Jhon").ToList();
```

But how I can generate the where conditions dynamically based on any number of conditions I receive
Also there is a plan to include Date filters in case there is some datetime nodes in json such as `BirthDate>12051995`.
I am not sure how I can dynamically filter using any number of input filter conditions.

Comment: what do you mean by  i can't achieve everything?

Comment: why you didn't use json.net deserializer?

Comment: Deserialize JSON --> Convert to List of Objects --> LINQ .Where() filter data.

Comment: @YongShun ok, I tried this and works. var res = (result as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray).Where(x => x["Age"].ToString() =="23" && x["EmpName"].ToString()=="Jhon").ToList();  But how I can generate the where conditions dynamically based on any number of conditions

Answer (score 3):

To get this working in a traditional way, you'll need to perform 3 steps:

- define a class to contain the data
- deserialize the json into a list of objects
- use linq to query your selection

You can do the same thing for the departments.
If you need to join them in any way, use `.Join`. If the JSON is mixed, you can create a single class containing all the properties and use that to query.

---

So for the simple case: first define a class to represent you object:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmpID {get;set;}
    public string EmpName {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

Then deserialize and query:

put at the top:

```
using System.Text.Json;
```

```
public void Main()
{
     //deserialize into a list
     List<Employee> employees = 
                JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Employee>>(yourJsonString); 

     //query
     var result = employees.Where(c => c.Age == 23 && c.EmpName == "Jhon");
     
     //show results
     foreach (var employee in result)
         Console.WriteLine(employee.EmpID);
}
```

---

#### As by update:

Depending on your use case you have a couple of options:

- a fixed number of dynamic properties
- a truly dynamic query

##### A fixed number of dynamic properties

You can achieve a more dynamic setup with the following:

```
//define the filterable properties
//note they are nullable
int? age = null;
int? id = null;
string name = null;

//apply them in a query
//
//note: if one of the filter properties is not set, 
//      that side of the && expression evaluates to "true"
var result = employees.Where(c => (age == null ? true : c.Age == age) && 
                                  (id == null ? true : c.EmpId == id) &&
                                  (name == null ? true : c.EmpName == name));
```

##### a truly dynamic query

Now here things start to get tricky. One possible option is to generate a string based query, with the help of a libary like [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamic-linq.net/)

Comment: Thanks. But how I can generate dynamic where conditions, I have updated question with more details.

Comment: @techresearch: see update

Comment: Additionally, if you have more questions beyond the scope of your original question, I suggest to ask a new question; it will get more attention :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have almost nailed it. :)

1. Instead of using `DeserializeObject` and then converting it to `JArray` prefer `JArray.Parse`

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("sample.json");
var semiParsedJson = JArray.Parse(json);
```

2. Instead of using `ToList` after `Where` prefer `JArray` constructor which can work well with an `IEnumerable<JToken>`

```
const string IdField = "EmpID", NameField = "EmpName", AgeField = "Age";
const StringComparison caseIgnorant = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

var idEq29 = semiParsedJson.Children()
    .Where(token => string.Equals(token[IdField].Value<string>(),"29", caseIgnorant));

Console.WriteLine(new JArray(idEq29).ToString());
```

3. The other queries can be implemented in the very same way

```
var ageEq23AndNameJhon = semiParsedJson.Children()
    .Where(token => string.Equals(token[AgeField].Value<string>(), "23", caseIgnorant)
                    && string.Equals(token[NameField].Value<string>(), "Jhon", caseIgnorant));

Console.WriteLine(new JArray(ageEq23AndNameJhon).ToString());
```

```
var ageEq29 = semiParsedJson.Children()
    .Where(token => string.Equals(token[AgeField].Value<string>(), "29", caseIgnorant));

Console.WriteLine(new JArray(ageEq29).ToString());
```

---

**UPDATE #1**: Enhance proposed solution
With the following extension method

```
public static class JArrayExtensions
{
    public static JArray Filter(this JArray array, Func<JToken, bool> predicate)
        => new JArray(array.Children().Where(predicate));
}
```

you can greatly simplify the filtering

```
var idEq29 = semiParsedJson
    .Filter(token => string.Equals(token[IdField].Value<string>(),"29", caseIgnorant));

var ageEq23AndNameJhon = semiParsedJson
    .Filter(token => string.Equals(token[AgeField].Value<string>(), "23", caseIgnorant))
    .Filter(token => string.Equals(token[NameField].Value<string>(), "Jhon", caseIgnorant));

var ageEq29 = semiParsedJson
    .Filter(token => string.Equals(token[AgeField].Value<string>(), "29", caseIgnorant));

Console.WriteLine(idEq29);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(ageEq23AndNameJhon);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(ageEq29);
```

---

Or you can push it even further. If all the fields store string values then you can define the extension method like this:

```
public static class JArrayExtensions
{
    public static JArray Filter(this JArray array, string field, string value)
        => new JArray(array.Children().Where(GenerateFilter(field, value)));

    private static Func<JToken, bool> GenerateFilter(string field, string value)
        => (JToken token) => string.Equals(token[field].Value<string>(), value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

The the filter queries are super simple :D

```
var idEq29 = semiParsedJson
    .Filter(IdField,"29");

var ageEq23AndNameJhon = semiParsedJson
    .Filter(AgeField, "23")
    .Filter(NameField, "Jhon");

var ageEq29 = semiParsedJson
    .Filter(AgeField, "29");

Console.WriteLine(ageEq23AndNameJhon);
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine(idEq29);
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine(ageEq29);
```